# MATLAB expression on left side

Tags: matlab

Can someone please explain the following MATLAB expression:

```
Matrix_l(2,:,1:5)=FX1(:,1:5)
```

I understand that all rows columns 1 to 5 from `FX1` are copied. What I dont follow is the left side expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LHS-Matrix is a [kind of 3D-Object](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html). Thus you are inserting all field from all rows and columns 1 to 5 from FX1 into "second layer" of Matrix_I all rows and columns 1 to 5.
You can think of that as a slice of 3D-cube resulting in a 2D plane into which your data from FX1 gets inserted.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes that helped. Learning phase. Thanks  lot.

Comment: I just edited my post - you can look further into http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html . Happy learning. And, please mark that answer as solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

As I don't know the dimensions of your actual matrix, I have taken the dimensions of my own convenience.

`FX1` of dimensions `5x7`
`Matrix_l` of dimensions `5x5x6`

To understand physically, A vertical slice (visualize a black board) is copied to 2nd Horizontal slice (visualize the floor) of a 3D matrix.

[image]

The first 5 columns of the 2D matrix (i.e the one at the right - `FX1` in your case) is copied to 2nd row and 1st 5 units in the 3rd dimensions of your 3D matrix (i.e the one at the left - `Matrix_l` in your case)

Also, [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) can handle even more higher dimensions. Physically imagining those would be impossible. Still it's worth to know how this works.

Also take a look at [`Indexing`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) and [`Colon(:)`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) operator for more.

Comment: +1 for me.  It's actually nice to see a visualization of what is actually happening when performing matrix slicing.

Comment: Whenever you're finished your school work, I've created a MATLAB chat room for us to discuss things MATLAB related, or for discussions that span beyond the limitations of a single comment.  Visit us when you have time! - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab